# JSON.parse not working for changing a string into an object

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a string

```
{ city : Chicago , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : New York , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Portland , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city :null, country :null, name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Mexico City , country : mx , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Boston , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Los Angeles , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : London , country : gb , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Los Angeles , country : us , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Chicago , country : us , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial }
```

What I am trying to do is turn this string into an object where I can iterate and print out the city, country, and name for each one.  So far I have figured out how to split the string to print out each line individually.

```
str = str.split('},{');
for(var i =0; i < str.length; i++)
{
      alert(str[i]);
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to convert the string to an object where I can print out the city, country, name, etc.

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON, so you cannot use `JSON.parse`. What creates this string? Any chance you make it produce JSON? That would be the best solution.

Comment: From what I assume, your string is missing the enclosing `[]` without which it is not valid json

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It's also missing a ton of double quotes around all the properties and values...

Comment: When producing JSON, you may want to use a validator such as [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate whether the JSON that was created by your program is syntactically correct.

Comment: If you can generate correctly formatted JSON, this becomes entirely easy. As @FelixKling asked, what is generating the string above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the correct initial idea.

However, after the split method, you will still need to map every pair of `key:value` like this:

```js
var str = '{ city : Chicago , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : New York , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Portland , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city :null, country :null, name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Mexico City , country : mx , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Boston , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Los Angeles , country : us , name : Somebody , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : London , country : gb , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Los Angeles , country : us , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial },{ city : Chicago , country : us , name : Aaron , plan : quarter90wtrial }';

var result = str.split('},{').map(function(itemStr) {
    var itemObj = {};

    // here we map each "key:value" pair
    itemStr.replace(/.*?(\w+) *: *(.*?) *[,}]/g, function(match, key, val) {
        itemObj[key] = val;
    });
    return itemObj;
});

console.log(result)
```

You can see how the regular expression is working here: https://regex101.com/r/E5tg26/1

Hope it helps.